# Pros and cons of using a cursor (in SQL server)

Tags: sql-server, database-cursor

I asked a question here [Using cursor in OLTP databases (SQL server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316550/using-cursor-in-oltp-databases-sql-server)

where people responded saying cursors should never be used.

I feel cursors are very powerful tools that are meant to be used (I don't think Microsoft supports cursors for bad developers).Suppose you have a table where the value of a column in a row is dependent on the value of the same column in the previous row. If it is a one time back end process, don't you think using a cursor would be an acceptable choice?

Off the top of my head I can think of a couple of scenarios where I feel there should be no shame in using cursors. Please let me know if you guys feel otherwise.

1. A one time back end process to clean bad data which completes execution within a few minutes.
2. Batch processes that run once in a long period of time (something like once a year).

If in the above scenarios, there is no visible strain on the other processes, wouldn't it be unreasonable to spend extra hours writing code to avoid cursors? In other words in certain cases the developer's time is more important than the performance of a process that has almost no impact on anything else.

In my opinion these would be some scenarios where you should seriously try to avoid using a cursor.

1. A stored proc called from a website that can get called very often.
2. A SQL job that would run multiple times a day and consume a lot of resources.

I think its very superficial to make a general statement like "cursors should never be used" without analyzing the task at hand and actually weighing it against the alternatives.

Please let me know of your thoughts.

Comment: Looks like Sql Server 2012 will support the case of getting the value from the prior row in a set based way.

Comment: "A stored procedure called from a web site" is way too vague. If a cursor is the most reasonable choice to solve a problem, and the procedure has to be called from a web page...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several scenarios where cursors actually perform better than set-based equivalents. Running totals is the one that always comes to mind - look for Itzik's words on that (and ignore any that involve SQL Server 2012, which adds new windowing functions that give cursors a run for their money in this situation).

One of the big problems people have with cursors is that they perform slowly, they use temporary storage, etc. This is partially because the default syntax is a global cursor with all kinds of inefficient default options. The next time you're doing something with a cursor that doesn't need to do things like `UPDATE...WHERE CURRENT OF` (which I've been able to avoid my entire career), give it a fair shake by comparing these two syntax options:

```
DECLARE c CURSOR 
    FOR <SELECT QUERY>;

DECLARE c CURSOR 
    LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
    FOR <SELECT QUERY>;
```

In fact the first version represents a bug in the undocumented stored procedure sp_MSforeachdb which makes it skip databases if the status of any database changes during execution. I subsequently wrote my own version of the stored procedure (see [here](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior)) which both fixed the bug (simply by using the latter version of the syntax above) and added several parameters to control which databases would be chosen.

A lot of people think that a methodology is not a cursor because it doesn't say `DECLARE CURSOR`. I've seen people argue that a while loop is faster than a cursor ([which I hope I've dispelled here](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/26/bad-habits-to-kick-thinking-a-while-loop-isnt-a-cursor)) or that using `FOR XML PATH` to perform group concatenation is not performing a hidden cursor operation. Looking at the plan in a lot of cases will show the truth.

In a lot of cases cursors are used where set-based is more appropriate. But there are plenty of valid use cases where a set-based equivalent is much more complicated to write, for the optimizer to generate a plan for, both, or not possible (e.g. maintenance tasks where you're looping through tables to update statistics, calling a stored procedure for each value in a result, etc.). The same is true for a lot of big multi-table queries where the plan gets too monstrous for the optimizer to handle. In these cases it can be better to dump some of the intermediate results into a temporary structure first. The same goes for some set-based equivalents to cursors (like running totals). I've also written about the other way, where people almost always think instinctively to use a while loop / cursor and there are [clever set-based alternatives that are much better](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/07/bad-habits-to-kick-using-loops-to-populate-large-tables).

UPDATE 2013-07-25

Just wanted to add some additional blog posts I've written about cursors, which options you should be using if you *do* have to use them, and using set-based queries instead of loops to generate sets:

[Best Approaches for Running Totals - Updated for SQL Server 2012](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals)

[What impact can different cursor options have?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options)

Generate a Set or Sequence Without Loops: [[Part 1]](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) [[Part 2]](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2) [[Part 3]](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)

Answer (score 6):

The issue with cursors in SQL Server is that the engine is set-based internally, unlike other DBMS's like Oracle which are cursor-based internally.  This means that when you create a cursor in SQL Server, temporary storage needs to be created and the set-based resultset needs to be copied over to the temporary cursor storage.  You can see why this would be expensive right off the bat, not to mention any row-by-row processing that you might be doing on top of the cursor itself.  The bottom line is that set-based processing is more efficient, and often times your cursor-based operation can be done better using a CTE or temp table.

That being said, there are cases where a cursor is probably acceptable, as you said for one-off operations.  The most common use I can think of is in a maintenance plan where you may be iterating through all the databases on a server executing various maintenance tasks.  As long as you limit your usage and don't design whole applications around RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) processing, you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

In general cursors are a bad thing. However in some cases it is more practical to use a cursor and in some it is even faster to use one. A good example is a cursor through a contact table sending emails based on some criteria. (Not to open up the question if sending an email from your DBMS is a good idea - let's just assume it is for the problem at hand.) There is no way to write that set-based. You could use some trickery to come up with a set-based solution to generate dynamic SQL, but a real set-based solution does not exist.

However, a calculation involving the previous row can be done using a self join. That is usually still faster than a cursor.

In all cases you need to balance the effort involved in developing a faster solution. If nobody cares, if you process runs in 1 minute or in one hour, use what gets the job done quickest. If you are looping through a dataset that grows over time like an [orders] table, try to stay away from a cursor if possible. If you are not sure, do a performance test comparing a cursor base with a set-based solution on several significantly different data sizes.

Comment: +1 I agree with much of that you've said, though previous row calculations can get pretty complex to write with most set-based solutions, for example running totals (discarding pre-release functionality for now).

Answer (score 1):

I had always disliked cursors because of their slow performance.  However, I found I didn't fully understand the different types of cursors and that in certain instances, cursors are a viable solution.

When you have a business problem that can only be solved by processing one row at a time, then a cursor is appropriate.

So to improve performance with the cursor, change the type of cursor you are using.  Something I didn't know was, if you don't specify which type of cursor you are declaring, you get the Dynamic Optimistic type by default, which is the one that is the slowest for performance because it's doing lots of work under the hood.  However, by declaring your cursor as a different type, say a static cursor, it has very good performance.

See these articles for a fuller explanation:

[The Truth About Cursors: Part I](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2010/05/truth-about-cursors-part-1.html)

[The Truth About Cursors: Part II](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2010/05/truth-about-cursors-part-2.html)

[The Truth About Cursors: Part III](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2010/05/truth-about-cursors-part-3.html)

I think the biggest con against cursors is performance, however, not laying out a task in a set based approach would probably rank second.  Third would be readability and layout of the tasks as they usually don't have a lot of helpful comments.

SQL Server is optimized to run the set based approach.  You write the query to return a result set of data, like a join on tables for example, but the SQL Server execution engine determines which join to use: Merge Join, Nested Loop Join, or Hash Join.  SQL Server determines the best possible joining algorithm  based upon the participating columns, data volume, indexing structure, and the set of values in the participating columns. So using a set based approach is generally the best approach in performance over the procedural cursor approach.

Answer (score 0):

They are necessary for things like dynamic SQL pivoting, but you should try and avoid using them whenever possible.